# Animation of Conformal Mappings

Tags: matlab, animation, complex-numbers

In this [movie](http://www.dimensions-math.org/CH56_Clip4.mov) the conformal mapping fz = -1/z is visualized as a continuous transformation of an image to the distorted result. How was this made?  I am working with conformal mappings in Matlab and I would like to know a method to generate the intermediate steps of an arbitrary conformal transformation in analogy to this movie.

Comment: What's wrong with the [doc](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/exploring-a-conformal-mapping.html) ? Without further information, I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: @obchardon: I know your link but my question can not be reduced to this. In this doc the input and mapped output are described but no method to generate intermediate steps like in the animation.

Answer (score 1):

One old trick is to use surface with `FaceColor = texturemap` with Z=0. A texturemapped surface with Z=0 is basically an image, but it lets you mess with the X&Y coordinates of the underlying grid to do this sort of warping.

You'd want 2D arrays for your XData & YData. Those are the ones you'll manipulate with the mapping. Your ZData would be an array of the same size which was all zeros. Then the CData array would be an image. If you wanted to use a 20x20 grid, it might look something like this:

```
m = 20;
n = 20;
[x,y] = meshgrid(m,n);
img = imread('myimage.png');
h = surf(x,y,zeros(m,n),img,'FaceColor','texturemap');
```

Then you can manipulate h.XData and h.YData to animate changing the mapping.

```
for t = 0:.05:1
    [newx, newy] = mymapping(x,y,t);
    h.XData = newx;
    h.YData = newy;
    drawnow
end
```

Comment: I have never used surf but I think I get your first part. The question is the "mymapping(x,y,t)" part: given the example  -1/(x+1i.*y) above, how is t coming into play?

Comment: Right, so to create an animation you'll want to show motion from your start point to your end point. I was using t as a placeholder for that. Basically you're going to want some function which takes [x,y] to [x,y] when t==0, and [x,y] to -1/(x +i y) when t==1. It might be as simple as linear (ie. (1-t) times identity transform plus t times your new transform). But I expect you'll want to try out some variations to see what looks good.

Answer (score 0):

With the following code I can generate a sequence of images that could be considered as a transformation or animation using the linear equation (1-t) * 1 + t * (1./(a.*(x+1i.*y))); But it is in no way that what is seen in CH56_Clip4.mov. Additionally t = 0.00 delivers a monochrome result.

```
[h_i, w_i, ~] = size(img);

% INITIALIZE IN-MESHGRID & NORMALIZE [0 1]
[xi,yi] = meshgrid(linspace(0,w_i+1,w_i),linspace(0,h_i+1,h_i));
xi = (xi/w_i); yi = (yi/h_i);

% INITIALIZE OUT-MESHGRID & NORMALIZE [-1 1]
[xo,yo] = meshgrid(1:w_i, 1:h_i);
xo = (xo/w_i)*2 - 1; yo = (yo/h_i)*2 - 1;

% GENERATE SURFACE
h = surf(xo, yo, zeros(w_i, h_i), img, 'FaceColor', 'texturemap');

% INITIALIZE OUT-IMAGE
img_out_t = zeros(h_i, w_i, 3);   

for t = 0.00:0.1:1.0
    % DISTORTION, SEPARATE & NORMALIZE [0 1]
    fxiy = (1-t) * 1 + t * (1./(1.2.*(xo+1i.*yo)));        
    h.XData = real(fxiy); xo1 = h.XData;
    h.YData = imag(fxiy); yo1 = h.YData;
    xo1 = (xo1+1)/2; yo1 = (yo1+1)/2;       
    % INTERPOLATION                                                        
    for k = 1:3; img_out_t(:,:,k) = uint8(interp2(xi, yi, img(:,:,k), xo1, yo1, interpol_meth)); end; imwrite(uint8(img_out_t), ['img_out_t_', num2str(t), '.jpg'], 'jpg', 'Quality', 98);
end
```